# What's wrong with this neumorphism design?

Tags: logo, style

I'm trying to create a logo using *neumorphism* learned from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlSLdEB3lzg). After hours of tweaking I still couldn't get it right.

I know there's something wrong but couldn't know if that's with the color, or the strokes in my logo or something else, I couldn't make it look as expected. Here's the [figma link](https://www.figma.com/file/nDF8ZbNM8WhSLyzEu9ppHt/LOGO?node-id=0%3A1). How do I improve it?

[image]

**Edit**: Do you think this one is better?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at other [neumorphism](https://uxdesign.cc/neumorphism-in-user-interfaces-b47cef3bf3a6) examples you should quickly notice a few key details:

- outer highlight and shadow are subtle and have low contrast compared to the background. You could fix yours by just making them transparent.
- the light and shadow are also very soft, you need to increase the blur on yours.

Check also the example below:

[image]

Comment: I did not read the whole linked article, but "neumorphism" is a clearly a play on "skeuomorphism" which means, basically "pretend this is an actual artifact." So the question becomes "what are we creating the illusion of?" From what I can tell, the answer looks like "embossed, pressed card stock" i.e. paper sculpture. Many of the key logos and calls to action though are in opposition to the paper stock: they are applied decals in the metaphor.

Comment: @Yorik what's your point?

Answer (score 1):

Like Luciano said, your shadow and highlight on the main element are too extreme.

Inside on the letters, the problem is in the colors. The highlight should be a lighter shade of the object, while the shadow should be a darker shade of whatever is beneath it. I would also recommend blurring them a bit more